# Calculate 3D Rectangle from 4 projected points on screen

Tags: geometry, vectors, 3d, plane-geometry, projection

Given 4 known projected points on the screen, I need to calculate a 3D rectangle where the 4 projected points coincide with the rectangle corners from the `o` perspective.

Here you can visually see the problem:

[image]

The red points are known and I need to calculate the yellow points.

Assumptions:

- o = (0,0,0)
- I can calculate a point in the line from the projected points $(p_1,p_2,p_3,p_4)$ using a sphere with $radius = 1$ $(sp_1,sp_2,sp_3,sp_4)$.
- The middle point in the rectangle can be known, calculating the sphere point as well with the intersection between the great arcs formed by the diagonals. Indeed, this point should be in the rectangle.

Using the line formula for the 4 points:

$p_1' = sp_1 + t_1*\vec{osp_1}$

$p_2' = sp_2 + t_2*\vec{osp_2}$

$p_3' = sp_3 + t_3*\vec{osp_3}$

$p_4' = sp_4 + t_4*\vec{osp_4}$

$t_1$, $t_2$, $t_3$ and $t_4$ are the variables to be calculated.

Some conditions I found:

- Adjacent sides must be 90 degrees

$\mathrm{\vec{p_1'p_2'}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\vec{p_1'p_4'}} = 0$

$\mathrm{\vec{p_2'p_1'}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\vec{p_2'p_3'}} = ​0$

$\mathrm{\vec{p_3'p_2'}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\vec{p_3'p_4'}} = ​0$

$\mathrm{\vec{p_4'p_1'}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\vec{p_4'p_3'}} = ​0$

- Opposite sides must have the same length

$||\vec{p_1'p_2'}|| = ||\vec{p_4'p_3'}||$

$||\vec{p_2'p_3'}|| = ||\vec{p_1'p_4'}||$

- Opposite sides must be parallels

$\mathrm{\vec{p_1'p_2'}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\vec{p_4'p_3'}} = ​||\vec{p_1'p_2'}||*||\vec{p_4'p_3'}||$

$\mathrm{\vec{p_3'p_2'}}\!\cdot\!\mathrm{\vec{p_4'p_1'}} = ​||\vec{p_3'p_2'}||*||\vec{p_4'p_1'}||$

But there is something I'm missing. I have tried to solve in Mathematica (with the `Solve` command) but I didn't have luck. It gets stuck forever in "calculating...".

Can you help me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the four points can be chosen at will, because once you find a rectangle, any plane parallel to it will cut the lines at the vertices of a similar rectangle.

Comment: Yes. The middle point (diagonal intersection) in the sphere will be the 3D point. With this point and the normal I can calculate the 4 points as well. Because I'm interested in the X,Y,Z rotation in that point.

Comment: There are MANY such rectangles.

Comment: @Moti I need just one containing the middle point in a sphere with radius = 1. Getting the normal vector of the plane is valid for me too.